# Strange pandas date_range behavour

Tags: python, pandas

The pandas `date_range()` function is showing a strange behaviour when the hours between the start and end dates do not match and the frequency is set to *Months*.

```py
>>> pd.date_range("2020-05-31 22:00:00", "2020-08-29 21:00:00", freq="1M")

DatetimeIndex(['2020-05-31 22:00:00', '2020-06-30 22:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

In this example, I would expect '2020-07-31 22:00:00' to be present in the index, but it is not.

Even though, the following examples work as expected:

```py
>>> pd.date_range("2020-05-31 22:00:00", "2020-08-29 22:00:00", freq="1M")

DatetimeIndex(['2020-05-31 22:00:00', '2020-06-30 22:00:00',
               '2020-07-31 22:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')

>>> pd.date_range("2020-05-31 22:00:00", "2020-08-29 23:00:00", freq="1M")

DatetimeIndex(['2020-05-31 22:00:00', '2020-06-30 22:00:00',
               '2020-07-31 22:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

It also happens if Datetime objects are provided rather than strings:

```
>>> s = pd.to_datetime("2020-05-31 22:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> e = pd.to_datetime("2020-08-29 21:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

>>> pd.date_range(s, e, freq="1M")
DatetimeIndex(['2020-05-31 22:00:00', '2020-06-30 22:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

Is this a bug or is there something I am missing?

Pandas v1.1.0

Comment: it seems like a bug. I would expect the same behavior.

Comment: It's complicated. I can respond in a bit, but `'M'` is a `<MonthEnd>` frequency, which **is a non-fixed frequency**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have found out is using time less than the one mentioned in the starting date won't list out the last result either you can use time greater than the starting date's one

```py
>>> pd.date_range("2020-05-31 22:00:00", "2020-08-29 23:00:00", freq="1M")

DatetimeIndex(['2020-05-31 22:00:00', '2020-06-30 22:00:00',
               '2020-07-31 22:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

OR

Instead of using "1M" as value for frequency you can use pandas DateOffset function which would help you in getting the desired result.

```py
>>> pd.date_range("2020-05-31 22:00:00", "2020-08-29 21:00:00", freq=pd.DateOffset(months=1))

DatetimeIndex(['2020-05-31 22:00:00', '2020-06-30 22:00:00',
               '2020-07-30 22:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: months=1>')
```